Wild Reverse Draw 4 Card as final card with two players in UNO Show 'Em No Mercy
In UNO Show 'Em No Mercy with 2 players:
If you play your last card and it is a Wild Reverse Draw 4 Card.
Is the game over or does the action from the card immediately force you to draw four cards?

You have won the game.
From the UNO Show 'Em No Mercy rules:

Winning:
When a player plays their final card, they win.


